# Rest Template Response Body

Tags: java, spring, rest, jsf, primefaces

I have a method that calls an endpoint to post a customer How can i get only the message "EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS" from the ResponseBody of Rest Template in order to show it in the FacesContext

```
         try {
        return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8030/addCustomer", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
           catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {

        var facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Sorry", e.getResponseBodyAsString()));
        return 
                        ResponseEntity.status(e.getRawStatusCode()).headers(e.getResponseHeaders())
                .body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```

This is the response Body

```
  {"httpStatusCode":400,"httpStatus":"BAD_REQUEST","reason":"BAD REQUEST","message":"EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS","timestamp":"11-04-2022 03:52:43"}
```

Comment: You can map the response into Map or custom DTO using Jackson object mapper and then get message

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any built-in way to access the *message* property. However, since the response body is in JSON, you could parse the body to a JSON object and then get the field value from that object.

Comment: Thank you so much Zephyr i convert it to a Json Object and then get the message and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the responseBody to a JsonNode and use the function findValue to get the property you want.

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), JsonNode.class);
mapper.convertValue(node.findValue("message"), String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an example:

```
val msg = ""
val response = restTemplate.exchange(
  "http://localhost:8030/addCustomer",
  HttpMethod.POST,
  HttpEntity<T>(headers),
  Array<Any>::class.java
)
response.body?.forEach { it ->
  val data = it as LinkedHashMap<String,Any>
  msg = data["message"].toString()
}
return msg
```

PS: I'm sorry the example is in kotlin code